# Web-how big websites are splitting load and manage théier database

Tags: networking, web, load

I was asking to myself how big websites like Google and Facebook are splitting the load between théier server ? 
And how they manage their big database ? How they know which servers have got the info (id/username/...)? 
Thanks in advence :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Sharding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_(database_architecture)) is the method of dividing up the database. You could do it by the first letter of the user's name, but more typically by first taking a hash of the username.

For databases which are largely read-only, such as Google's web index, the entire database can also be replicated. I believe theirs is sharded and stored in RAM across many machines.